# Dataloader: removing records that do not match the source file

Tags: data-loader

What I'd like to do is upload a csv file and have the resulting salesforce object match that csv exactly.

I can use upsert to modify and create new records, but the resulting object will contain old entries. Is there a way to remove records from an object if they do not match the source csv being uploaded?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, no, the Data Loader can't do this. You would need either a paid tool that provides synchronization capability, or you'd have to delete the old entries that are left over as as separate transaction; upload the CSV, query records that haven't been modified in the past X amount of time, and then delete them. You could also write an Apex Code script to save a bit of time with the deleting part.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to first delete all records and then insert the new records.

1. `Export` all existing records.
2. Use the export file as your data source for a `Delete` operation.
3. `Insert` new records.

If you want to maintain `CreatedDate` and `CreatedBy` info, along with any data for fields you don't intend to overwrite, you'll have to add a step between 1 and 2 where you filter out the records yourself.